# Accomplishing DB Query in Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way I would go about moving this request below, into a eloquent one? I am trying to locate and then merge all duplicate records based on name and death date. The original model is `CemeteryContact`.

```
$duplicates = DB::table('cemetery_contacts')
->select('last_name','first_name','date_death', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('last_name', 'first_name','date_death')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
->where('last_name','!=', 'Unknown')
->get();
```

Thanks!

Comment: It will be exactly same except `DB::table('cemetery_contacts')` you would be using `CemeteryContact`

Comment: @JitendraYadav - I replaced that, but have another side question, how do I include the `id` field but not have to place it in the `groupBy` portion of the query?

Comment: @inuShiva if the group will always have the same id then what's the harm if including it in the groupBy? Otherwise things like e.g. `MAX(id) as id` can work to have the largest id of the group show (after all you *should* have to tell your database which id of the group you want if it's not being grouped on)

Comment: @apokryfos - Because if I add the id to the end of the groupBy, there are no results returned. Whereas if I don't include the id in the groupBy, the proper results are returned.

Comment: If the id is unique on every row then that would be expected right? If there's for example 10 duplicate records each having its own unique id , which id would you want shown in the group?

Comment: @apokryfos - with the script that I'm trying to work around, I don't have a specific care on if it's the first or last, it would just be helpful to be able to use the ID to identify rows that have one or more duplications.

Comment: If you're using MySQL then you can add `DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids')` in your select to get all of them comma separated. Something like `DB::raw('MAX(id) as id')` would also work to just show the largest one